# Help with JFreeChart overlay

Tags: overlay, jfreechart, scale, mismatch

I'm having an issue with a JFreeChart overlaid graph. I'm using JFreeChart 1.0.13. What I am trying to do seems like it was easier to do in earlier versions of JFreeChart?

The graph shows a line chart and a bar chart. The data range plotted by the line chart for the Y axis is in the 0-100 range, and the axis for the bar chart is in the 0-5 range.

Individually, when I lay out each chart and paint it, they look great. Here's an example:

Bar Chart[image] 
Line Chart[image]

But when I overlay them, the bar chart gets scaled down to look incredibly useless... presumably because the scales of the two datasets are so different.

Example:
[image]

What I really want is to split the series data for the two datasets, and display the 0-100 range for the line chart on the left hand Y axis and to have the bar chart displayed full size as in my first example below, but have the scale 0-5 displayed on the right hand Y axis side of the graph.

To create the graph, I am first creating the bar chart using an XYSeriesCollection, adding the data and creating the plot...

```
XYSeriesCollection histogramDataset= new XYSeriesCollection();
XYSeries xy= new XYSeries("Temp");
xy.add(100,0.0);
xy.add(101,0.3769791404875597);
histogramDataset.addSeries(xy);
...
final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis("Temperature C");
xAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
final ValueAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Percent Time above Temperature");
final XYItemRenderer renderer = new XYBarRenderer();

final XYPlot plot = new XYPlot((XYDataset) histogramDataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
```

Then I create the line chart in a similar way and add the second series to the plot...

```
final XYSeries xy = new XYSeries("First");
final XYDataset xySeriesData = new XYSeriesCollection();
final XYItemRenderer xyLineRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
xyLineRenderer.setSeriesShape(0, new Line2D.Double(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
xyLineRenderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(4.5f));
xy.add(100,100.0);
xy.add(101,100.0);
xyseriesData.add(xy);
plot.setDataset(1, xySeriesData);
plot.setRenderer(1, xyLineRenderer);
plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
```

My suspicion is that somehow each graph needs to be it's own plot and combined together. Can anyone help? What I am going for here is something like this:
[image]

Except I don't want the bar chart to be a background image. The X axis should be the same, and the Y axis should be on the right hand side with the proper scale that allows the graph to be shown full size.

Any/all replies are appreciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you're adding a second data set and renderer to your plot, but you're forcing them to use the same range axis. Instead, give the plot a new [`NumberAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) for the range of the second data set.

As an aside, don't overlook the axis related example in the [*JFreeChart Demo*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp), and don't underestimate the value of the [*JFreeChart Developer Guide*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html).

Comment: Not affiliated with http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/; just a satisfied customer and sometime contributor.

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction. Adding:
final ValueAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Percent Time at Temperature");
  
plot.setRangeAxis(1, yAxis);
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(0, 1); 

MapDataSetToRange was the key...