# JFreeChart: is it possible to combine a stacked bars and line chart combined?

Tags: jfreechart

As in this mockup:

[image: Layered chart]

I know it is possible to have charts display next to each other using `org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot`, but is it possible to have them overlaid, possibly using different Y axes (one for the stacked bars to the left of the chart, and one for the line chart shown to the right of the chart)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the chart entitled [*DualAxisDemo1*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), shown among the *Multiple Axis Charts*, is an example. In addition to a second data set and renderer, you need a second axis, as discussed in this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702083). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242696/230513) combines two renderers; this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362809/230513) combines two axes.