# Multiple axes on the same data

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to have two axes on the same data.

The data is a couple of `DefaultTableXYDatasets`. The plot is a `XYPlot`, and I have two `XYLineAndShapeRenderers` and one `StackedXYAreaRenderer2`.

All data is in meters for the y-values, and I want to have one axis displaying it in meters and one axis displaying it in feet. Now this feels like a common thing to do, but I can't decide on the most obvious way to do it. One way that works would be to duplicate the data and have the y-values in feet, then add another `NumberAxis` and be done with it.

But I thought it would be wiser to subclass `NumberAxis`, or inject some functionality into `NumberAxis` to scale the values. Or should I go with the first approach?

What do you think?

Comment: Replace the natural language with programming language in your question. A much better way to start a conversation on SO :)

Comment: The [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) has lots of multiple axis examples.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't seen any example where there's more than one axis to one dataset. I might be mistaken, I'll check them again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually i settled on this solution, it might not be the most elegant but it worked. I have a second axis `feetAxis`, and added a `AxisChangeListener` on the first axis called `meterAxis`. When the `meterAxis` changes set the range on `feetAxis`.

I used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, otherwise the range would be incorrect when zooming out of the chart, then the `feetAxis` would only go from 0 to 1. Didn't check why though.

```
feetAxis = new NumberAxis("Height [ft]");
metersAxis = new NumberAxis("Height [m]");
pathPlot.setRangeAxis(0, metersAxis);
pathPlot.setRangeAxis(1, feetAxis);

metersAxis.addChangeListener(new AxisChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void axisChanged(AxisChangeEvent event) {

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               feetAxis.setRange(metersAxis.getLowerBound() * MetersToFeet, metersAxis.getUpperBound() * MetersToFeet);
                }
           });
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid duplicating data, you can use the `XYPlot` method [`mapDatasetToRangeAxes()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#mapDatasetToRangeAxes-int-java.util.List-) to map a dataset index to a list of axis indices. In the example below, `meters` is the principle axis, and the range of the corresponding `feet` axis is scaled accordingly, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363401/230513). Note that `invokeLater()` is required to ensure that the `feet` axis is scaled *after* any change in the `meters` axis.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.event.AxisChangeEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13358758/230513
 */
public class AxisTest {

    private static final int N = 5;
    private static final double FEET_PER_METER = 3.28084;

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {
        XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection();
        final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Data");
        for (int i = -N; i < N * N; i++) {
            series.add(i, i);
        }
        data.addSeries(series);
        return data;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
        NumberAxis meters = new NumberAxis("Meters");
        NumberAxis feet = new NumberAxis("Feet");
        ValueAxis domain = new NumberAxis();
        XYItemRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
        XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, domain, meters, renderer);
        plot.setRangeAxis(1, feet);
        plot.setRangeAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
        List<Integer> axes = Arrays.asList(0, 1);
        plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxes(0, axes);
        scaleRange(feet, meters);
        meters.addChangeListener((AxisChangeEvent event) -> {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                scaleRange(feet, meters);
            });
        });
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Axis Test",
            JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
        return chart;
    }

    private void scaleRange(NumberAxis feet, NumberAxis meters) {
        feet.setRange(meters.getLowerBound() * FEET_PER_METER,
            meters.getUpperBound() * FEET_PER_METER);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("AxisTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(createChart(createDataset())));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new AxisTest().display();
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `JCheckBox` to flip between the two series, meters & feet, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513). Using the methods available to `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, you can hide a second series' lines, shapes and legend. The series itself must be visible to establish the axis range.