# Map dynamic dataset to different axis in JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, timeserieschart

This is my code at the moment (updated):

```
public DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;
private static final String TITLE = "Stripchart";
private static final int COUNT = 3 * 60;
private static final int TEMP_MIN = -10;
private static final int TEMP_MAX = 50;
private static final int AIR_MIN = 0;
private static final int AIR_MAX = 20;
private static final int INSO_MIN = 0;
private static final int INSO_MAX = 1;
public void draw(Data data) {
    float[] newData = new float[3];
    newData[0] = (float) data.getTemp();
    newData[1] = (float) data.getAir();
    newData[2] = (float) data.getInso();
    dataset.advanceTime();
    dataset.appendData(newData);
}

private ChartPanel createChart() {
    dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(3, COUNT, new Second());
    dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2016));
    dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 0, "Temperature");
    dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 1, "Air");
    dataset.addSeries(new float[1], 2, "Insolation");
    final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            TITLE, "hh:mm:ss", " ", dataset, true, true, false);
    final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
    ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domain.setAutoRange(true);
    NumberAxis temp = new NumberAxis("Temperature");
    NumberAxis air = new NumberAxis("Air");
    NumberAxis inso = new NumberAxis("Insolation");

    plot.setRangeAxis(0, temp);
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(0, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
    plot.setRangeAxis(1, air);
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
    plot.setRangeAxis(2, inso);
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(2, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
    List<Integer> axes = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);
    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxes(0, axes);
    temp.setRange(TEMP_MIN, TEMP_MAX);
    air.setRange(AIR_MIN, AIR_MAX);
    inso.setRange(INSO_MIN, INSO_MAX);

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(result);

    return chartPanel;
}
```

The units are  °C , m/s and lux respectively.

Everything works fine but it does not map the series as exactly as I want.

[image]

As you can see, the blue line and green line are not mapped with the second and third axis.

Any ideas to get it working?

Your help will be appreciated.

// **Updated** :

I have tried using this but the result is the same:

```
List<Integer> axes = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxes(0, axes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fragment, I see three axes and one dataset with three series. Your calls to [`mapDatasetToRangeAxis()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#mapDatasetToDomainAxis-int-int-) appear to assume three distinct datasets. As suggested in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362809/230513), you may want something like this:

```
List<Integer> axes = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxes(0, axes);
```

The approach assumes that the three series have linearly dependent scales, and you'll have to scale the individual axes accordingly, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362809/230513). You could try separate datasets, but I haven't tried it.

Addendum: Based on your update, it appears that the three datasets are not commensurate. Instead, create three individual datasets. Use the first in your chart factory, use `setDataset()` to establish the other two and map them accordingly:

```
final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
    TITLE, "hh:mm:ss", " ", createDatasetTemp(), true, true, false);
…
plot.setDataset(1, createDatasetAir());
plot.setDataset(2, createDatasetInso());
plot.setRangeAxis(0, temp);
plot.setRangeAxisLocation(0, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
plot.setRangeAxis(1, air);
plot.setRangeAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
plot.setRangeAxis(2, inso);
plot.setRangeAxisLocation(2, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(0, 0);
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(2, 2);
```

Comment: `List<Integer> axes = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);`
 `plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxes(0, axes);`

It does not work as I want.

What should I do when the three series have independent scales?

Comment: I see °C and w/m^2. What are the units of "Air"? For more specific guidance, , please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Edited.
Btw, is there a way to reset all the series in the dataset?

Comment: You can just set the upper and lower bounds of each axis to the corresponding defined values. I don't see a reset method in `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`.

Comment: updated with more information. Your help will be appreciated, trashgod

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean; try separate datasets, as outlined above.