# Change Plot label position in a Combined Plot JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is there a way to change the position of the Category Plot Labels (title) (censored with black bars in the image) to be on top of the chart and / or aligned vertically to each other?

[image: JFreeChart combined plot]

Here's the classes I use to construct it.

```
var renderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
...
var yAxis = new NumberAxis();
...
var xAxis = new CategoryAxis(title);
...
CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
...
var combinedPlot = new CombinedRangeCategoryPlot();
combinedPlot.add(plot, weight);
...
```

I'm using version 1.0.19 of JFreeChart since newer versions produce some visual artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There has been a misunderstanding: I meant the labels, "Plot 0" and "Plot1", in your example; and I'm asking for the ability to move them on top of the chart…

Invoke `setDomainAxisLocation()` on each *subplot* domain axis to move the axis and its label. Alternatively, obtain the required axis references from the `List<CategoryPlot>` shown below.

```
plot0.setDomainAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_LEFT);
plot1.setDomainAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_LEFT);
```

[image]

> I only need those "Plot 0" and "Plot1" labels on top, not the tick labels…

You can hide the tick labels as desired using `setTickLabelsVisible(false)`, and you can have multiple axes, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13358758/230513).

[image: imge]

To adjust the tick label orientation, invoke `setCategoryLabelPositions()` on each *sublot* comprising the combined plot. Do this either

- When the plot is created.

  ```
    CategoryAxis axis0 = new CategoryAxis("Plot 0");
    axis0.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
    CategoryPlot plot0 = new CategoryPlot(…, axis0, …);
    …
    CategoryAxis axis1 = new CategoryAxis("Plot 1");
    axis1.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
    CategoryPlot plot1 = new CategoryPlot(…, axis1, …);
  ```
- After creating the combined plot.

  ```
    CombinedRangeCategoryPlot combinedplot = new CombinedRangeCategoryPlot(…);
    …
    List<CategoryPlot> list = combinedplot.getSubplots();
    list.get(0).getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
    list.get(1).getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
  ```

Vertical labels are illustrated below.

[image]