# Wrap Plot label in a Combined Plot JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is there a way to wrap plot label for Category axis?

I'm facing a problem where these titles merge between the plots. It would be best if they would wrap at least once. Is it possible?

The titles are dynamic.
[image]

Here's the classes I use to construct it.

```
var renderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
...
var yAxis = new NumberAxis();
...
var xAxis = new CategoryAxis(title);
...
CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
...
var combinedPlot = new CombinedRangeCategoryPlot();
combinedPlot.add(plot, weight);
...
```

I'm using version 1.0.19 of JFreeChart since newer versions produce some visual artifacts.

Comment: AFAIK, axis label wrapping is not supported, although multiple axes, each with its own label, are permitted, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362809/230513); alternatively, tooltips support wrapping in HTML.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for your input. Might have to resort to splitting the title contents between two axis.