# How to draw combined plot for timeseries in JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I wanted to create a timeseries plot where I would be able to accomodate more that 2 chart of timeseries. Tried searching a lot on the net, any ideas how to do it.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a [`CombinedDomainXYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html), you can add multiple series to an existing chart, as seen in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo). You can also add another axis to an existing chart, as seen discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705498).

Addendum:

> I am looking for time series plot. The scale should be in minutes.

A [time series chart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createTimeSeriesChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) is just an `XYPlot` in which the domain is a `DateAxis` and the range is a `NumberAxis`, as seen in the code of the [`createTimeSeriesChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1886) factory method. You can use [`Minute`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Minute.html) for the domain interval, as discused [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603723).

Comment: @chai: I've elaborated above.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of plot you want. You may want two series in the same plot or two series in different plots.

For two series in one plot you would need two datasets and two renderers.

```
plot.setDataset(0, dataset0);
plot.setRenderer(0, renderer0)

plot.setDataset(1, dataset1);
plot.setRenderer(1, renderer1)
```

In the above code you can use all kinds of datasets and renderers which your plot supports.

For two separate plots in the same graph use a CombinedDomainXYPlot. Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCombinedXYPlotDemo1.htm).

Furthermore you can use one dataset with more than one series by adding the values to the correct series:

```
dataset.addValue("series", value);
```