# JFreeChart Crosshair on a combined plot

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

I'm using a combined plot composed of 2 graph which share the same X axis (by sharing, I mean, the timeframe is the same for the two graph). The upper graph is a regular timeseries while the lower chart is a barchart. I would like to display a crosshair on the combined chart as a whole... Right now I can display crosshair only on each graph separately even thought I have specify on the combined plot that I wanted to display the crosshair. To be more explicit, I can't synchronise both crosshair... Any idea on how to achieve that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to work if you use a shared domain axis, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702083/help-with-jfreechart-overlay/3705498#3705498) and as shown in [`CrosshairDemo2`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp)? In addition, an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might help clarify your usage.